# Splitting the sourcecode before passing to Quality gates

Tags: sonarqube, checkmark, checkmarx

I have a build where the Checkmarx scan is taking more than four hours to scan the full source code. Is there any way to split the source code into three or four packages and scan separately. So that we can scan them parallelly and run the scans faster. If you know please specify how we can split the source code to different packets to sent to Scan.

Comment: You ask 2 questions.The first is whether a checkmark scan can be split.The second is how to do it in Sonarqube. Please ask one question only

Comment: Please consider only Checkmarx for now

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Checkmarx does not support linking results between source codes. If your code contains some stand-alone components like micro-srvices, you can split your source code to various Checkmarx scans.

But if you splitted your code to separated scans, and there is a "flow", value in the code that passed between the splitted source code, and it expose a volnurability, Checkmarks won't recognize it.

Comment: i have added another question regarding checkmarx . could you check that
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60207378/checkmarx-scan-through-commandline-is-throwing-errors

Comment: I sew your question but I can't answer it. About this Q, if my answer helps you, please upvote and (if) mark it as answer