# Checkmarx scan through commandline is throwing errors

Tags: checkmarx

I am using the below command line to start the Checkmarx scan.

```
 runCxConsole Scan -v -CxServer "http://IP"  -projectName "test\Project" -CxUser "domain\username" -CxPassword "password" -Locationtype "TFS" LocationPath "$/TFSRepo/test/Main" -LocationURL "http://tfs.domain.test:8080/tfs" -LocationUser "username@domain.com" -LocationPassword "pasword" -preset "Testpreset"
```

Unfortunately, it is not working and I am getting the below error

```
 [2020-02-13 11:47:06,901 INFO ] Verbose mode is activated. All messages and events will be sent to 
 the console or log file.
 [2020-02-13 11:47:06,901 INFO ] CxConsole version 8.90.2
 [2020-02-13 11:47:06,917 INFO ] CxConsole scan session started
 [2020-02-13 11:47:06,917 INFO ]
 [2020-02-13 11:47:06,917 INFO ] Default configuration file location: C:\CxConsolePlugin- 
 8.90.2\CxConsolePlugin-8.90.2\config\cx_console.properties
 [2020-02-13 11:47:07,495 FATAL] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Unable to parse due to 
 missing or incorrect parameters. Recheck the provided parameters and try again.
 [2020-02-13 11:47:07,495 ERROR] Failure - General error occurred - error code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed '-' in your LocationPath that's why it is not recognized as a correct parameter and also make sure there is no extra space in between this command. (You have given one extra space before -projectName it will throw error in command line).

Pass this command

runCxConsole Scan -v -CxServer "http://IP" -projectName "test\Project" -CxUser "domain\username" -CxPassword "password" -Locationtype "TFS" -LocationPath "$/TFSRepo/test/Main" -LocationURL "http://tfs.domain.test:8080/tfs" -LocationUser "username@domain.com" -LocationPassword "pasword" -preset "Testpreset"